# Using MapPath from a worker thread

Tags: asp.net, wcf, httpcontext, server.mappath

I have a WCF service method that's running in a worker thread I spin from another method. 
 I need to map a relative service app path ("~/Templates/a.template") to the physical path ("D:\Web\Templates\a.template"), but I can't use `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath` because `HttpContext.Current` is null in a worker thread. How else can I reach `MapPath` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually figured out a workaround - I use HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPath to get physical path of WCF service, and add the relative path to it.

Answer (score 45):

Use [System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath.aspx).

No `HttpContext` required and it does the same work.